# Apache nifi CSVRecordLookupService: 'csv-format' is not a supported property

Tags: apache-nifi

I have a legacy apache nifi workflow. One of the processors shows an invalid component message:

[image]

In the properties section of this processor, I see a property 'Lookup Service' mapped to CSVRecordLookupService, and clicking on 'Go to' takes me to a list of configured services where I see that state for CSVRecordLookupService is invalid with the following error message:

[image]

I'm not able to understand what the error message conveys.

PS: Workflow was made with nifi 1.10, and I am on nifi 1.22.0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I checked version `1.11.0` NiFi and there was a default option for `csv-format`: `Default` (https://github.com/apache/nifi/blob/68d5d025dc3d2c3e137155c9cdb90c7449a61970/nifi-nar-bundles/nifi-standard-services/nifi-lookup-services-bundle/nifi-lookup-services/src/main/java/org/apache/nifi/lookup/CSVRecordLookupService.java#L89C66-L89C66).

In the latest version (`1.23.2`) NiFi has default option for `csv-format`: `default` (https://github.com/apache/nifi/blob/dec043e590f26ba2f3594f4f297dcd2b7e565ab7/nifi-nar-bundles/nifi-standard-services/nifi-lookup-services-bundle/nifi-lookup-services/src/main/java/org/apache/nifi/lookup/AbstractCSVLookupService.java#L47)

I prefer to change the value in the XML template or manually change it to `default` in `CSVRecordLookupService`

Comment: I set it manually to 'default' on nifi Ui, but problem persists. But as its optional, so I removed it and my flow completed. But I also see another property by name 'CSV Format', which is mandatory.

Comment: Apparently the underlying name of the property was changed between 1.10 and 1.22, which makes the existing property invalid, and you're correct that you have to set the required `CSV Format` property and remove the old `csv-format` property.

Comment: @mattyb, thanks for confirmation. Btw, is there a quick way to know about all such legacy properties that may not be valid anymore in latest nifi versions?

Comment: Yes it should have been in the Migration Guide (https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/NIFI/Migration+Guidance) but it was overlooked. I have since added it to the guide.